# React: useContext value is not updated in the nested function

Tags: reactjs, nested-function, use-context

I have a simple context that sets some value that it get from backend, pseudo code:

```
export const FooContext = createContext();

export function Foo(props) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('/api/get-value').then((res) => {
            const data = res.data;
            setValue(data);
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <FooContext.Provider value={[value]}>
            {props.children}
        </FooContext.Provider>
    );
}

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Foo>
                <SomeView />
            </Foo>
        </div>
    );
}

function SomeView() {
    const [value] = useContext(FooContext);
    
    console.log('1. value =', value);
    
    const myFunction = () => {
        console.log('2. value = ', value);
    }
    
    return (<div>SomeView</div>)
```

Sometimes I get:

```
1. value = 'x'
2. value = null
```

So basically for some reason the value stays as null inside the nested function despite being updated to `'x'`.

Comment: Where you are calling the `myFunction`?

Comment: It seems here in the code, myFunction hasn't been called

Comment: Looks like a stale closure to me, although I can't tell since your pseudo code functions isn't called anywhere

Comment: The myFunction is called everytime I click a button(not in the code). The button is part of the component.

Comment: Added my updated answer in which how you can call the nested function outside the parent function?@Bob Sacamano

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Explanation

This is such a classic [stale closure problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=stale+closure&oq=stale+closure). I cannot tell where the closure goes outdated because you didn't show us how you use the `myFunction`, but I'm sure that's the cause.

You see, in JS whenever you create a function it will capture inside its closure the surrounding scope, consider it a **"snapshot" of states at the point of its creation**. `value` in the question is one of these states.

But calling `myFunction` could happen sometime later, cus you can pass `myFunction` around. Let's say, you pass it to `setTimeout(myFunction, 1000)` somewhere.

Now before the 1000ms timeout, say the `<SomeView />` component has already been re-rendered cus the `axios.get` completed, and the `value` is updated to `'x'`.

At this point **a new version** of `myFunction` is created, in the closure of which the new value `value = 'x'` is captured. But `setTimeout` is passed **an older version** of `myFunction` which captures `value = null`. After 1000ms, `myFunction` is called, and print `2. value = null`. That's what happened.

---

#### Solution

The best way to properly handle stale closure problem is, like all other programming problems, to have a good understanding of the root cause. Once you're aware of it, code with caution, change the design pattern or whatever. Just avoid the problem in the first place, don't let it happen!

The issue is discussed here, see [#16956](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16956) on github. In the thread multiple patterns and good practices are suggested.

I don't know the detail of your specific case, so I cannot tell what's the best way to your question. But a very naive strategy is to use object property instead of variable.

```
function SomeView() {
    const [value] = useContext(FooContext);

    const ref = useRef({}).current;
    ref.value = value;
    
    console.log('1. value =', value);
    
    const myFunction = () => {
        console.log('2. value = ', ref.value);
    }

    return (<div>SomeView</div>)
}
```

Idea is to depend on a stable reference of object.

`ref = useRef({}).current` create a stable reference of same object `ref` that don't change across re-render. And you carry it within the closure of `myFunction`. It acts like a portal that "teleports" the state update across the boundary of closures.

Now even though stale closure problem still happens, sometimes you might still call outdated version of `myFunction`, it's harmless! Cus the old `ref` is the same as new `ref`, and it's property `ref.value` is guaranteed to be up-to-date since you always re-assign it `ref.value = value` when re-rendered.

Comment: This answer is very helpful. Yeah, this is really a stale closer problem :)

Comment: Very helpful.  If you're using Typescript  you need to specify the types in this line:  const ref = useRef({mything1:myType, myThing2:string}).current;

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you need to provide some default value to your context if no value then set the default value as null.

```
export const FooContext = createContext(null);
```

Mostly there is two way for passing the value in the Provider Component. You can pass by an `object` or `tuple` to `value` props in the Provider component.

I'll give you an example by passing an `object` in the Provider Component. @dna has given an example of a `tuple`.

```
<FooContext.Provider value={{value,setValue}}>
     {props.children}
</FooContext.Provider>
```

Now if you want to use that value in another component you need to destructure the object like this

```
const {value, setValue} = useContext(FooContext);
```

---

If you have called the nested `myFunction()` correctly like shown below then the value would also be  `x` instead of null.

```
function SomeView() {
    const [value] = useContext(FooContext);
    
    console.log('1. value =', value);
    
    const myFunction = () => {
        console.log('2. value = ', value);
    }
    SomeView.myFunction = myFunction; //updated line
    return (<div>SomeView</div>)
}
```

```
<button onClick={SomeView.myFunction}>Click</myFunction>
```

Output :

```
1. value = 'x'
2. value = ' x'
```

> Now, the question is why it is returning a single character value instead of the state value.

In Javascript, a string is an array of characters.
Eg.

```
const string = ['s','t','r','i','n','g'];
//This is equivalent to
const string = "string";
```

In your case, your state value may be a string. So, when you destructuring the string you will get the first character of the string.

You will understand more if I give you an example.

```js
const string = "subrato";

const [str] = string;
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the wrong part is in the provider value, you do this:

```
...
<FooContext.Provider value={value}> // <-- 'value' is simply a value
    {props.children}
</FooContext.Provider>
...
```

and in `<SomeComponent />` you destructure the context value in this way:

```
const [value] = useContext(FooContext);
```

But this is wrong beacuse you set the provider value as simple value not as tuple.

**SOLUTION** To make your destructuring working, you shoud set your provider like this

```
...
<FooContext.Provider value={[value]}> // <---- USE TUPLE NOTATION
    {props.children}
</FooContext.Provider>
...
```

Comment: I'm sorry for misleading you. I set the value in provider as a tuple. I didn't write the pseudocode correctly. In the real case it is a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your value state is giving back a value inside the function and giving a null inside a nested function is because of these reasons.

1. First reason is you are passing an arrow function which means it will only give back a value on an onClick function.

   ```
   const myFunction = () => {
        console.log('2. value = ', value);
    }
   ```
2. Second reason is that you have not called the nested function `myFunction` that you made.

Rather than do this and it will work:

- Call your function inside the `SomeView()`.

  ```
   myFunction();
  ```
- Update your function.

  ```
    function myFunction() {
      console.log("2. value = ", value);
    }
  ```
- Or if you want it run with your old code pass an onClick listener which will fire your myFunction() and will console.log the value.

  ```
   const myFunction = () => {
      console.log("2. value = ", value);
    };

   return <button onClick={myFunction}>Click me</button>;
  ```