# React ı cant reach current state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state, use-effect

```
React.useEffect(

() => {
  const users = [  
    {id:123123123,
      name:"mert",
      del: <deleteButton  onClick={()=>console.log(users)} />
    }]
    setusers(users)


}, [])
```

hello i have a problem
I created a useState called [users, setusers]
and in useeffect, I have assigned a delete function for each user.
this delete function needs to reach users state

But the problem starts here. When I want to reach users through the delete function,
I get the initial state of the state, (the state at the time I created the first user object)

Comment: Hi! Can you provide the code for the full component in your question? I think it would be helpful for us to have some more code to look at.

Comment: From your description it seems that you are shadowing the `users` variable, i.e. your initial `users` array from the `useEffect` is used in the `onClick` rather than the `users` returned from `useState`. In short, you should either rename `const users =[...]` to something else, for example `const initalUsers = [...]` or remove that variable entirely and do `setusers([...])`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: useContext value is not updated in the nested function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64259890/react-usecontext-value-is-not-updated-in-the-nested-function)

Comment: This is yet another stale closure problem. Take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64442841/3617380) at another question. The solution also applies to your problem.

Comment: Put `users` as a dependency to the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: Also, putting JSX (React elements) directly in the state is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

In your useEffect hook you define a const variable called `users`.
In the onClick Event you output the const variable `users` and not the state variable `users`.

Which means const users is not equal to state.users 
Rename your const variable 'users' and see if anything changes.